# stm32 where should I compute data

Tags: stm32, interrupt, dma

I am using ADC with DMA to sample sound with 48kHz sample rate. I am using `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback` function and when the flag is up I need to process those samples.

In the callback I only fill the array with samples and set bool `readComplete` to true and then in while(1) I check if `readComplete == true` and if so I process the data in while loop.

The problem is that when I debug the program I can see that the priority of callback is higher than while(1) loop and it is randomly jumping to while. It is like the while(1) loop is not executing everytime.

The question is, where or how should I process that data?

Answer (score 0):

Your Procedure of setting a readComplete Flag is correct because you should keep your program running in interrupt context as short as possible. (The ConvCpltCallback is called by the STM HAL from interrupt context.)

Interrupts always have a higher priority than your main loop.
When are you starting the next ADC conversion process? Is it possible, that the callback routine is overwriting your array data before you have completely processed them in the while loop? To fix this, you can try increasing the size of the DMA transfer which will increase the time between the callbacks.

Please edit your question and post a short summary of the relevant sourcecode so we have a better insight.